# Convert multiple object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object say

```
SiteData(2)
[
0: { site_name: "ABC", totalPercent: 15}
1: { site_name: "XYZ", totalPercent: 31}
]
```

I need to convert  it into single array which should be stored in a variable as

```
var SiteData= [[ABC,15],[XYZ,31]]
```

I have tried with `Object.values(SiteData);`

But i am not getting the desired output

Comment: Your data is not well-formatted, you should have an object instead of an array since your are using keys inside

Answer (score 1):

**You need to apply `Object.values` twice**, once for the outer object, and once for the inner objects:

```js
const SiteData = {
  0: { site_name: "ABC", totalPercent: 15},
  1: { site_name: "XYZ", totalPercent: 31}
};

const result = Object.values(SiteData).map(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object was wrong. And use `map` and `Object.values` to do that

```js
var a=
[
{0: { site_name: "ABC", totalPercent: 15}},
{1: { site_name: "XYZ", totalPercent: 31}}
];
console.log(a.map(e=>Object.values(e).map(x=>Object.values(x).map(t=>t))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the values in the right order, which is dependent on insertation order or if you have more propterties than wanted, you could use an array of the wanted keys to separate the values.

```js
var data = [{ site_name: "ABC", totalPercent: 15 }, { site_name: "XYZ", totalPercent: 31 }],
    keys = ['site_name', 'totalPercent'],
    result = data.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k]));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
let data = [
    { site_name: "ABC", totalPercent: 15},
    { site_name: "XYZ", totalPercent: 31}
];
let tempData= [];

for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
tempData.push([data[i].site_name, data[i].totalPercent])
}

console.log(tempData)
```